# XmlDocument from instance of class generated with xml.exe

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xmldocument, signed

What is the best way to get signed xml (as string) from data got from, for example, webservice? 
I have pretty complex schema for that XML-document and would like to generate class with xsd.exe, instantiate it with data and then sign it with SignedXml, but I can't figure out how to get XmlDocument from instance of class created from schema. (SignedXml only reads XmlDocument).

I'm not sure about this, but I've undestood that schema also includes some information about signing, and if it's possible, it would be nice if SignedXml could directly read that from schema, i.e., through that class generated with xsd.exe

Answer (score 0):

To get an xml document from an instance of a class generated by xsd.exe use XmlSerializer.Serialize().

As for the "signed" part of your question, I think you need clarify further.